# Why does OkHttp silently replace ws:// or wss:// schemes?

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

I've been attempting to use `OkHttp WebSockets` with a `wss://` URL on Android to no avail. When I pass a URL with `wss://` scheme it's replaced with `https://`. It then, of course fails.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed. Is there a better websocket library out there? Here is the service I'm working on.

```
class WebsocketService(private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) : 
WebSocketListener() {

private lateinit var webSocket: WebSocket
private lateinit var serverListener: ServerListener

fun connect(listener: ServerListener) {
    this.serverListener = listener


    val request = Request.Builder().url(SOCKET_URL).build()

    okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, this)
}

override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket?, response: Response?) {
    super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
    Timber.e("On Open %s", response.toString())
}

override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket?, t: Throwable?, response: Response?) {
    super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
    Timber.e("On Failure %s", response.toString())
}

override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket?, code: Int, reason: String?) {
    super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
    Timber.e("On Closing %s", reason)
}

override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
    super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
    Timber.e("On Message %s", text)
}

override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, bytes: ByteString?) {
    super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes)
    Timber.e("On Message Bytes %s", bytes)
}

override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket?, code: Int, reason: String?) {
    super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
    Timber.e("On Closed %s", reason)
}


enum class ConnectionStatus {
    DISCONNECTED,
    CONNECTED
}

interface ServerListener {
    fun onNewMessage(message: String)
    fun onStatusChange(status: ConnectionStatus)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpUrl class OkHttp uses to model URLs only models the `http:` and `https:` schemes. But this is not likely to be the reason your web socket is failing. The scheme change is intended as an implementation detail inside OkHttp and shouldn’t impact behavior.

Comment: Thanks!  Sometimes just some affirmation that you're not crazy is helpful.

Comment: Turns out it was an Action Cable issue.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the fix? Don't leave us hanging

Comment: @androidDeving Can you please let us know what the issue was? I'm currently facing same (with actioncable) and I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What if the server responds differently to https and wss requests? I'm connecting to a server where any https traffic is redirected as if it was a normal HTML web page request so preserving the scheme is vital.